# QBuffer in a QRunnable may or may not generates error QObject::moveToThread: Current thread is not the object's thread

Tags: qt, qt5.3

I have a derived class from a QRunnable object. It is doing small image processing tasks. It looks like follow:

```
void ImageProcessor::run()
{
    int bytesPerLine;
    if(_format == QImage::Format_RGB32)
        bytesPerLine = _width * 4;

    QImage img(_buffer, _width, _height, bytesPerLine, _format);

    QTransform transform;
    transform.rotate(90);
    QImage rotatedImage = img.transformed(transform);


    _resultImage->clear();

    QBuffer buffer(_resultImage);

    buffer.open(QIODevice::WriteOnly);
    rotatedImage.save(&buffer, "JPG", 85);
    buffer.close();
}
```

My problem is when I execute my application, the following error message is displayed but not always. I may run it onother time and see nothing special.

```
QObject::moveToThread: Current thread (0x2012268) is not the object's thread (0x2007dc0). Cannot move to target thread (0x21a6218)
```

The only QObject derived class I use is QBuffer and this one is created locally in the executing thread. I don't understand why I'm getting this.

Any help would be appreciated!

I run this with QT 5.3, under Windows 7 and MSVC2010 32bits if it can gives any clues.

The following link to a sample application that recreates the issue. [ParallelImageProc.zip](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B8l0gTvsxiZkelZOVUZ3bVFSU28/view?usp=sharing) It contains a screenshot that show the actual result that I'm getting.

Thanks!

Comment: Are you sure that the described code actually produce that warning?

Comment: Absolutely. As soon I comment out the rotatedImage.save(...) which use the QBuffer object, no problems occurs any more. Also if I do this: Object * o = new QObject(); QBuffer buffer(_resultImage, o)
I'm always getting the error and not sporadically this time.

Comment: I've checked the QBuffer source code and it does not have any moveToThread calls. I think you should provide a minimal example that reproduces your problem.

Comment: I added a link to a sample test application if you want to have a look. Thanks

Comment: I've built your example with Qt 4.6.2 under CentOS and didn't have any problems. I've also used a QBuffer with a parent like in your previous comment and still everything worked fine.

Comment: I did few more experiments and if I add a small delay between each pool.start(), it is fine. It means that there is a piece of code behind the scene that doesn't like to be called simultaneously from different threads. You have maybe a different behavior because of Qt 4.6.2 or CentOS manage thread priorities differently.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I finally found the problem and I'm answering my own question in case it could help someone else.

So, the problem was not related to the fact that I was using a QBuffer object. I tried to do something similar to the following and no error messages was logged:

```
QBuffer buffer;
buffer.open(QBuffer::WriteOnly);
char buf[] = new char[100 * 1024 * 1024;
buffer.write(buf, 100 * 1024 * 1024);
delete [] buf;
buffer.close();
```

This made me perplex since the only class that derives from QObject was QBuffer. At the same, I was sure that the problem was caused by the call:

```
rotatedImage.save(&buffer, "JPG", 85);
```

After many tries and had a deep look into Qt source files, I figured out that I was wrong. There is still another class that inherits QObject. Image formats are managed using plugins behind the scene. The class that was generating me problems was QImageIOPlugin. In Qt source, those classes are loaded from a QFactoryLoader instance dedicated to image formats.

The [following thread](http://qt-project.org/forums/viewthread/13352/), even if it was for a different issue, helped me to point out directly at the origin of my displayed error message.

Since there is no way to directly access this factory loaded instance, the easiest way to solve the issue is to fake an image save into the desired format before using any threads. In my case, I simply added following lines in my main(...) function:

```
QImage image(10, 10, QImage::Format_RGB32);
QBuffer buffer;
buffer.open(QBuffer::WriteOnly);    
image.save(&buffer, "JPG", 85);
buffer.close();
```

In such a case, the QImageIOPlugin will be created before threads. There will be no error message and no problem in saving images as well into a QBuffer.

Hope this may help someone else. Cheers!!

Comment: This solved as well my issue while calling `QCameraImageCapture::capture()` in Qt5.5.1.